# how to execute two javascripts in one php file?

Tags: javascript, conflict

I've included two javascripts in one php file. First one is camera and 2nd is carouFredSel.  But they don't run together. If I remove the 2nd one, then 1st one works properly. If I keep both then only 2nd one runs. But I want to run both files. Somebody please help me to get out of it.

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='java_slider/scripts/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='java_slider/scripts/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='java_slider/scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script> 
    <script type='text/javascript' src='java_slider/scripts/camera.min.js'></script> 

    <script>
        jQuery(function(){

            jQuery('#camera_random').camera({
                thumbnails: true
            });
        });
    </script>




    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
    function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
    var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
    }
    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
    var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
    }
    function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
    var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
    if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
    for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
    if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
     }
   function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
   var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
     }
    //-->
    </script>
        <!-- include jQuery + carouFredSel plugin -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="java/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="java/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
        <!-- fire plugin onDocumentReady -->
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(function() {

                //  Basic carousel, no options
                $('#foo0').carouFredSel();

                //  Basic carousel + timer, using CSS-transitions
                $('#foo1').carouFredSel({
                    auto: {
                        pauseOnHover: 'resume',
                        progress: '#timer1'
                    }
                }, {
                    transition: true
                });

                //  Scrolled by user interaction
                $('#foo2').carouFredSel({
                    auto: true,
                    prev: '#prev2',
                    next: '#next2',
                    pagination: "#pager2",
                    mousewheel: true,
                    swipe: {
                        onMouse: true,
                        onTouch: true
                    }
                });

                //  Variable number of visible items with variable sizes
                $('#foo3').carouFredSel({
                    width: 360,
                    height: 'auto',
                    prev: '#prev3',
                    next: '#next3',
                    auto: false
                });

                //  Responsive layout, resizing the items
                $('#foo4').carouFredSel({
                    responsive: true,
                    width: '100%',
                    scroll: 2,
                    items: {
                        width: 400,
                    //  height: '30%',  //  optionally resize item-height
                        visible: {
                            min: 2,
                            max: 6
                        }
                    }
                });

                //  Fuild layout, centering the items
                $('#foo5').carouFredSel({
                    width: '100%',
                    scroll: 2
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css" media="all">
            .wrapper {
                background-color: #D1D1D1;
                width: 670px;
                box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999;
                margin: auto;
                height: 181px;
            }
            .list_carousel {
                height: 100px;
                width: 670px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            .list_carousel ul {
                list-style: none;
                display: block;
                padding-left: 0.5px;
            }
            #foo2{
                margin-left: 15px;
                margin-top: -10px;
            }
            .list_carousel li {
                font-size: 20px;
                color: #999;
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #eee;
                width: 194px;
                height: 155px;
                margin: 5px;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                margin-left: 8px;
            }
            .list_carousel.responsive {
                width: auto;
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            .clearfix {
                float: none;
                clear: both;
            }
            .prev {
                float: left;
                margin-left: 2px;
                margin-top: 80px;
            }
            .next {
                float: right;
                margin-right: 2px;
                margin-top: 80px;
            }
            .pager {
                float: left;
                width: 300px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .pager a {
                margin: 0 5px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            .pager a.selected {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .timer {
                background-color: #999;
                height: 6px;
                width: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="wrapper">      
    <a id="prev2" class="prev" href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image2','','images/left_arrow_hover.png',1)"><img src="images/left_arrow.png" name="Image2" width="21" height="28" border="0"></a>   
<a id="next2" class="next" href="#" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image4','','images/right_arrow_hover.png',1)"><img src="images/right_arrow.png" name="Image4" width="21" height="28" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: I think you included more than just 2 javascripts. But looks like you included jQuery twice.

Comment: You should reduce this to a minimal example of about 10-15 lines of code.  It will help you understand the problem better, and it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added `jquery-1.8.2.min.js` && `jquery.min.js`. Both are same , remove one of them

**EDIT**

Do the following steps:

remove `jquery-1.8.2.min.js`

Put `jquery.min.js` on the top of all other scripts

replace all `$(` with `jQuery(`

Comment: If I remove one of it then can't run both scripts. only one will work. I need to execute both.

Comment: @Jklyn No. It doesn't matter how many scripts you want to run. You only need to include jQuery once (unless in the rare case of having two scripts with incompatible versions of jQuery necessary, for which you'll need to look into noConflict).

Comment: Then why am I facing the problem? Please tell me what to do next?

Comment: Please is there anyone who could help me??

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman is there anything you can do to solve my problem?

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman I've listed some questions. Nobody has given me the correct answer to solve it. Since you've answered my first question correctly and solved my problem, I humbly request you to solve my other problems also. As I'm just creeping to this field, I'll be glad if you guide me. Thanks in Advance.